# Possible relation between internal and external magnetic field in Neutron Stars

Tags: magnetic-fields, astrophysics, neutron-stars, supernova

I am wondering about a topic that disturbs me and regarding which I haven't found enough literature about.

Neutron stars are thought to be highly magnetised objects. Generally one makes the distinction between the internal magnetic field, and external magnetic field (sometimes referred to as the poloidal field). The external magnetic field is the one involved in the spin-down of these objects, and is, to some extent, evaluable if one assumes a spin-down model and has access to the spin parameters (f, f-dot, etc...).
Not much can be done for the internal magnetic field instead, apart from model-dependent simulations.

To my knowledge, the two components might be of different nature, but I've always generally thought that the internal component was always some order of magnitude higher than the external one.

My question is, are there some hypotheses about a relationship between the two components? Is it completely wrong the idea that the two components might have completely unrelated magnitudes?

Comment: Poloidal is a word used to describe the geometry of the field. I'm not very clear what you are asking about. Magnetic field lines are continuous. If you asking what do we know about the interior fields of neutron stars - well it is mostly theoretical with a boundary condition that it must produce the B-field we infer exists externally. i.e. The two are certainly related.

Comment: I agree that I inadequately used the term 'poloidal'.
So my question was mainly about the relationship between the internal magnetic field in a neutron star and the inferred external one; my confusion comes from the fact that some works treat the 'external' magnetic field as a 'crustal confined' field, thus disentangled from the internal component. Then my question would be: is it wrong to completely disentangle the two?